# PHP with decimals and int

Tags: php, string, sorting, numeric

I maked database in php with table then put one colum int 
from php file i connect with this column and want to take integer information and sort from hight to low and this is correct but when the array take integers and sort from hight to low give me next numbers:

I put : 2,7,9,10,3,15,1
Araay give me : 9,7,3,2,1,15,10

auto covert to decimals why? Thansk...

---

RE>
is not strings its int into the column

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($potvrda)){
    $array[] = $row2["soS"] . "<br />";


    foreach ( $row2 as $key => $val ) {

        if (!empty($val) && $key!= "soS" ) {

            print $key . " : " . $val . "<br />";

        }

    }

} 
rsort($array);
    echo $array[0];
    echo $array[1];
    echo $array[2];
    echo $array[3];
    echo $array[4];
    echo $array[5];
    echo $array[6];
</code>
```

---

RE>
Daniel M Thanks alot rsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);ist the solution Thanks Again...

Comment: Looks like a lexicographic ordering; are you sure the array elements are integers and not strings?

Comment: +1 for punctuation. It's something that exists in most languages.

Comment: @eggyal: Because I'd like to help him but I've no idea what he wants.

Comment: Why are you adding a `<br />` in each array element?

Comment: @user1624648, don't forget to accept Daniel M's answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `rsort()` wrong.
As your values come from the DB, they are strings. And indeed, the *string* "15" is less than the string "9" as "15" starts with a "1".

To solve your problem, use the  `SORT_NUMERIC` flag:

```
rsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Further information: http://www.php.net/rsort